# Typeahead JS custom event not triggered

Tags: javascript, laravel, typeahead

I'm trying to trigger a custom event like:

**typeahead:select** but nothing happens.

My code is listing the info I want but then when I select nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong?

```
var route = "autocomplete";
$('.clientName').typeahead({
    minLength: 1,
    highlight: true,
    source:  function (term, process) {
      return $.get(route, { term: term }, function (data) {
            return process(data);
        });
    }

});

$('.clientName').on('typeahead:select', function(ev, suggestion) {
  alert("here");
  console.log('Selection: ' + suggestion);
```

});